# super(context , Database_Name , null , version) What does this line do?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Just now I am started working with the SQLite in Andriod. I know its a SQLiteOpenHelper's constructor. But What does this constructor do when it is triggered. Will it create a database or what ?. Seeking your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

according to the android docs **SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)**

> Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This
>   method always returns very quickly. The database is not actually
>   created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or
>   getReadableDatabase() is called.

you can read more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

The constructor just stores the parameters into member variables and checks that the version is at least 1. [See the source](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#97).

The database gets created when

- `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` is called.
- The database file didn't exist.

[See the source for that](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#getDatabaseLocked), too.